# How to represent an attribute of an entity on which entity is subdivided in an er diagram?

Tags: database, erd

I am making an er diagram for a vehicle rental company. The company has small car, luxury car and van as different vehicles where each type has separate rental costs, eg. small car at $100 per day, luxury for $200 and van for $150. If each vehicle had a different cost, then I could have used specialization but each vehicle of same type having same cost will increase redundancy. I could have made an abstract entity kind of thing, but have no idea whether such a thing exists in er diagram. How could I model it?

Comment: "Redundancy" is a vague general term. Explain what you mean by "increase redundancy" and why you think it is a problem here. Also read an intro to database design. Google re database/sql subtyping.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for specialization. Most of the cases specialization is needed in a ternary relationship.Or when some entity occurrences of an entity need extra attributes. This model can solve the redundancy problem.

[image]

**UPDATE** You can use combination of CarName and Cost as composite primary key for the table `Cost`

**UPDATE2** Since you have mentioned

> If each vehicle had a different cost

I gave the Cost to Car.

**UPDATE 3**
I recommend you to use the first model but what you want is being able to have Rental Cost both for CarType and Car.In this data model, it is optional for a car entity to have its own cost.  So, in this case, use specialization `{Optional, And}`. There won't be any redundancy.

[image]

When we are using `{Optional, And}` then you should create one table for Car and one table for CarCost.

Comment: Why not make cost dependent on car type, since the OP says "each type has separate rental costs"?

Comment: Using (CarName, Cost) as PK for the Cost table isn't sensible.

Comment: Because every car has its own cost.

Comment: Every car doesn't has its own cost, but each car type has

Comment: Check the update 3. In this data model, it is optional for a car entity to have its own cost.

Answer (score 0):

Subtyping is used when you need to have different attributes, relationships or constraints for subsets of a domain. In this case, the different types of cars all have the same attributes - type name and rental cost - and you didn't mention any other relationships or constraints, so we don't need subtyping (yet).

For your ER diagram, you can simply model car types and have cost an attribute of that:

[image: Car and CarType ER diagram]

This translates to a physical model like the following table diagram:

[image: Car and CarType table diagram]

Comment: In this ER model, a real object of CarType would not be created, so would it still be considered a strong entity?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean with "a real object of CarType would not be created". CarType (the entity set) is identified by its own attributes (CarTypeId) so its a regular entity set (Chen defined weak and regular entity sets, not strong entity sets).